# What are the standard MIPS macros?

Tags: assembly, mips, binutils

I am learning how to use the mips M4k processor but I am having a terrible time finding the standard mips assembler macros for instructions like LI, the imgtec instruction manuals are completely devoid of any mention of these. Would appreciate a link to documentation if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I think some can be implemented in more than one way.  Take gcc for example, use one of these pseudo instructions, assemble then disassemble and see what they produce.  And then go look in the assembler sources, to find what their opinion is.  A number if not all are somewhat obvious.

Comment: Yes as @old_timer says, macro syntax is usually determined by the assembler. I'm not familiar with the MIPS world, but x86 assemblers each have their own conventions. Some assemblers don't provide macros at all.

Comment: Things like `li` are called pseudo-instructions,not macros. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions